Actionbutton not updating in Shiny Module
I'm trying to update the label and icon of a ActionButton and I know there are similar questions but I just dont seem to get it to work.
nameUI <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(NS(id, "run"), "Run", icon = icon("bolt"))
  )
}

nameServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$run, {
      ns <- session$ns
      updateActionButton(session, inputId = ns("run"), label = "Running", icon = icon("sync", class = "fa-spin"))
      print("Running")
      Sys.sleep(3)
      updateActionButton(session, inputId = ns("run"), label = "Run Done", icon = icon("bolt"))
      print("Done")
    })
    
    
  })
  

  
}

app <- function() {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    nameUI("test")
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    nameServer("test")
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)  
}

app()


try actionButton(ns("run"), "Run", icon = icon("bolt")) and take ns <- session$ns outside of the observeEvent

That won't solve the main problem which is that the updateActionButton events are both executed at the end of the observeEvent - there's no way to update it in the middle

Any problems with modules are separate to the main issue of the updateActionButton events only being executed at the end of the observeEvent, so I have left that out. You can see here though that only the final updateActionButton has an effect. bslib::input_task_button does what you are trying to do though. The only limitation is that while there is bslib::update_task_button it doesn't seem to be able to update the label value like updateActionButton can. If that is essential though, it would be possible with some javascript.
library(shiny)

  ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("run1", "Run", icon = icon("bolt")),
    bslib::input_task_button("run2", "Run", icon = icon("bolt"), label_busy = "Running")
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$run1, {
      updateActionButton(session, "run1", label = "Running", icon = icon("sync", class = "fa-spin"))
      Sys.sleep(3)
      updateActionButton(session, "run1", label = "Run Done", icon = icon("bolt"))
    })

    observeEvent(input$run2, {
      Sys.sleep(3)
    })

  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Here's a solution with

a state machine (state_tracker and its switch statement)

and

session$onFlushed to only do the blocking sys.sleep() after the reactive system is flushed.

nameUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("run"), "Run", icon = icon("bolt"))
  )
}

nameServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns

    state_tracker <- reactiveVal("init")


    observeEvent(input$run, {
      if (state_tracker() == "init") {
        state_tracker("go")
      }
    })

    observe({
      switch(state_tracker(),
        "run" = {
          print("Running")
          session$onFlushed(\(x){
            Sys.sleep(3)
            state_tracker("Done")
          })
        },
        "go" = {
          updateActionButton(session,
            inputId = "run",
            label = "Running",
            icon = icon("sync",
              class = "fa-spin"
            )
          )
          state_tracker("run")
        },
        "Done" = {
          updateActionButton(session,
            inputId = "run",
            label = "Run Done",
            icon = icon("bolt")
          )
          print("Done")
          state_tracker("init")
        }
      )
    })
  })
}

app <- function() {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    nameUI("test")
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    nameServer("test")
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}

app()

